# How to check the return value of a function or Component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to check the return JSX of the following react components:

```
const App = () => {
  const nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

  return (
      <div>
        {courses.forEach(args => <Id id= {args}/>)}
      </div>
  )
}

const Id = ({id}) => {
      return (
          <div>
            {id}
          </div>
      )
    }
```

Now if run the following line:

`const x = <App />`

1. Will the value of x be - `<div> 1 </div> <div> 2 </div> <div> 3 </div>`... ?
2. How do i check the value of x? Console.log(x) is printing a something weird

Comment: Remember JSX isn't a thing in JavaScript... by the you're in the browser console, Babel (or your preferred transpiler) has done it's magic: https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAggBwTAvDAFASlQPhgHgBMBLANxwAlj8B6E8oA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3%2Ces2015-loose%2Ctypescript&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.5&externalPlugins=